# What selector selects all P elements with an id attribute, regardless of the id attribute's value?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was doing a css3 test and this question poped in:

> What selector selects all P elements with an id attribute, regardless of the id attribute's value?

I think I know how you can do it with jQuery, but how would you do it only with css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following selector will select any `p` element with an `id` attribute:

```
p[id]
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fW4sY/).

There's a list of selectors available within CSS from the official W3 website: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

The selector I've used above is an [Attribute Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) introduced by CSS2:

> `[att]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute, whatever the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

E[foo]  Matches any E element with the "foo" attribute set (whatever the value).

Don't need css3, it's here since css2.

Comment: The information is accurate, but you might lean towards providing a specific example of how to meet the requirements of the specific question.

Comment: I know @David, but I hate doing others (home?)work, online test, etc. I'm glat to share the little knowledge I have, link good sources of information, give a different point of view or review what "tired eyes" can't see in front of them... But I'll not do the "dirty work" for others to copy-paste. A simple google search with the title of the question (!?) as argument lead to the "source of all the knowledge of css selectors" in the first 10 results (first page, 5th result now). Seems for me he didn't made any effort, so mine is not bigger for this question.

Comment: there's really no need for insults... btw: every question here is someone elses work or homework.